# Multi-column select and modify of data table in R

Tags: r

I'm reading some raw log data and preprocesing it prior to parsing. I read the log and then add a column - draw$rule - to signify the parsing rule to be applied.

```
> raw<-readLines("20130205000046 firewall_log.txt")
> draw<-as.data.frame(raw)
> draw$rule <- 0
> head(draw)
                                                                                                                                    raw
1 2013 Feb  4 06:15:59 [UTM9S] [kernel] WAN2LAN[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN  OUT=LAN SRC=66.249.75.193 DST=192.168.1.38 PROTO=TCP SPT=42415 DPT=80 
2 2013 Feb  4 06:16:22 [UTM9S] [kernel] WAN2LAN[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN  OUT=LAN SRC=66.249.75.193 DST=192.168.1.38 PROTO=TCP SPT=63520 DPT=80 
3 2013 Feb  4 06:16:46 [UTM9S] [kernel] WAN2LAN[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN  OUT=LAN SRC=66.249.75.193 DST=192.168.1.38 PROTO=TCP SPT=55379 DPT=80 
4 2013 Feb  4 06:17:10 [UTM9S] [kernel] WAN2LAN[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN  OUT=LAN SRC=66.249.75.193 DST=192.168.1.38 PROTO=TCP SPT=49425 DPT=80 
5 2013 Feb  4 06:17:34 [UTM9S] [kernel] WAN2LAN[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN  OUT=LAN SRC=66.249.75.193 DST=192.168.1.38 PROTO=TCP SPT=34270 DPT=80 
6 2013 Feb  4 06:17:39 [UTM9S] [kernel] WAN2LAN[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN  OUT=LAN SRC=66.249.75.193 DST=192.168.1.38 PROTO=TCP SPT=35331 DPT=80 
  rule
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
```

Now I want to flag rows based on patterns matched in the raw log data. The statement below works up to a point, it picks the rows and flags draw$rule with 1.

```
> draw[grep("^.*ACCEPT.*PROTO=(TCP|UDP).*$",draw$raw),2] <- 1
> head(draw)
                                                                                                                                    raw
1 2013 Feb  4 06:15:59 [UTM9S] [kernel] WAN2LAN[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN  OUT=LAN SRC=66.249.75.193 DST=192.168.1.38 PROTO=TCP SPT=42415 DPT=80 
2 2013 Feb  4 06:16:22 [UTM9S] [kernel] WAN2LAN[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN  OUT=LAN SRC=66.249.75.193 DST=192.168.1.38 PROTO=TCP SPT=63520 DPT=80 
3 2013 Feb  4 06:16:46 [UTM9S] [kernel] WAN2LAN[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN  OUT=LAN SRC=66.249.75.193 DST=192.168.1.38 PROTO=TCP SPT=55379 DPT=80 
4 2013 Feb  4 06:17:10 [UTM9S] [kernel] WAN2LAN[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN  OUT=LAN SRC=66.249.75.193 DST=192.168.1.38 PROTO=TCP SPT=49425 DPT=80 
5 2013 Feb  4 06:17:34 [UTM9S] [kernel] WAN2LAN[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN  OUT=LAN SRC=66.249.75.193 DST=192.168.1.38 PROTO=TCP SPT=34270 DPT=80 
6 2013 Feb  4 06:17:39 [UTM9S] [kernel] WAN2LAN[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN  OUT=LAN SRC=66.249.75.193 DST=192.168.1.38 PROTO=TCP SPT=35331 DPT=80 
  rule
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
```

What I'm having difficulty with is extending the selection so that it only works on rows that match the regex AND have draw$rule set to zero, in other words only consider rows that have not been previously matched. I want to update the value of draw$rule in place rather than extracting a subset at this stage.

How do I modify the statement to achieve this? The end result is to have a sequence of statements like:

```
draw[<some selection condition 1> && draw$rule==0,2] <-1
draw[<some selection condition 2> && draw$rule==0,2] <-2
draw[<some selection condition 3> && draw$rule==0,2] <-3
  etc
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `grepl` insteade of `grep`. This function returns a logical vector the same length as its argument. Also, don't use `&&`, use `&` instead. `&&` is for single elements, while `&&` operates on vectors.